# Path-homotopic definition.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Given two paths $f,g: [0,1] \mapsto X $

Then their product is defined by $f\cdot g := \begin{cases}
f(2t) , \space 0\leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}\\
g(2t-1) ,\space  \frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq 1\\
\end{cases} $

Now it is said that $[f\cdot g] = [f]\cdot [g]$.

Where [-] is the homotopic class relative to $\{0,1\}$.

But I can't see why this is the case. Surely it could be the case where $h$ is path-homotopic to $f\cdot g$ but $h(1/2) \neq f(1)=g(0)$

Hence not every element in $[f\cdot g]$ can be represented by the product of two elements in $[f]$ and $[g]$ respectively?

Hope someone can clear this up!

Comment: Are you requiring your path homotopies to fix the endpoints?

Comment: This definition of product is usually done under the assumption that $f(0)=f(1) = g(0) = g(1)$. If the equality in the middle is not true, not even the product of $f$ and $g$ is a path. If the other constraints are not met, there is no way to multiply more than $f$ and $g$ together.

Comment: What is $\cdot$ in $[f] \cdot [g]$? Since those are classes, not paths, are you sure this is not a definition?

Comment: Yes. Sorry of course I was meaning that f(1)=g(0). (I am not needing that paths are loops though!)

Comment: Ben. This definition has not been stated to me. Have you heard of it before?

Comment: Are you thinking that the product of classes essentially tells to forget the meeting point?

Comment: Of course you have to say homotopy means homotopy rel end points. Then  every element of $[f]$ has the same end points as does $f$. We then define $[f].[g] $ to be $[f.g]$ for any representatives $f,g$ and you have to verify this is independent of those choices, that is, if $[f]=[f'],[g]=[g']$ then $[f.g]=[f'.g']$. Say if you have difficulties with this.

Comment: Thanks Ronnie. No problems with that.

Comment: $[f]\cdot[g]$ is not the set of products $f'\cdot g'$ for $f'\in [f]$ and $g'\in[g]$. The product $[f]\cdot[g]$ is usually **defined** to be $[f\cdot g]$, as Ronnie said.